# Stuck on a maximum likelihood problem

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> A random sample of size $n$ is taken from the pdf
>   $$f_Y(y;\theta)=\frac{2y}{\theta^2}, \quad 0 \le y  \le \theta$$ 
>   Find an expression for $\hat{\theta}$, the maximum likelihood estimation for $\theta$.

$$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2y_i}{\theta^2}= \frac{2^n \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{\theta^{2n}}\\
\ln(L(\theta)) = n\ln(2) + \ln\big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i\big)-2n\ln(\theta)$$
Normally at this point I would take the derivative. Let
$$T = \frac{d\big[\ln(L(\theta))\big]}{d\theta}=\frac{2n}{\theta}$$
But I am not sure if I have done something wrong to get to here because when I let $T=0$, I get $0=\dfrac{2n}{\theta}$.

Can anyone see something that I am missing maybe through ignorance or through silly error? Thanks.

This question is relating to using order statistics as maximum likelihood estimates. I'm reading about it now in the text book, but if someone knows how to do it, please do.

From me reading just now, obviously the differentiation does not work, so I have to actually look at the likelihood function itself and analyse it. 
$L(\theta)$ is maximised by minimising $\theta$, but from ordered statistics technique, theta cannot be less than than $Y_n$

So let me try this:

$$L(\theta) = \frac{2y}{y_n}$$

Comment: Ahhh, $\ln$, thanks for the heads up @AlexFrancisco

Comment: I think this has something to do with the domain being $[0,\theta]$ but I cannot work it out yet.

Comment: It has to do more than something with the domain when the support of the distribution depends on the parameter. Given the sample $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, what is the set of all admissible values of $\theta$? Can you see why differentiation isn't totally justified here?

Comment: No I cannot really @StubbornAtom please tell me intuitively why this does not make sense.

Comment: In fact, also remind me what "support" means too. @StubbornAtom

Comment: Support is what you call the domain of definition of the distribution. Or the sample space.

Comment: Thankyou @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the condition that $y\leq \theta$, the log-likelihood becomes
\begin{align*}
\ln(L(\theta)) &= n\ln(2) + \ln\big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i \mathbb 1(y_i\leq \theta)\big)-2n\ln(\theta)\\
&=n\ln(2) + \ln\big(\mathbb 1(\max_i(y_i)\leq \theta) \prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i \big)-2n\ln(\theta)\\
&=n\ln(2) + \ln(\mathbb 1(\max_i(y_i)\leq \theta)) + \ln\big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i \big)-2n\ln(\theta)\\
&=\begin{cases}
-\infty &\text{if }\theta<\max_i(y_i)\\
n\ln(2) + \ln\big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i \big)-2n\ln(\theta)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

This means you only consider $\theta\geq \max_{i} (y_i)$ and so since your derivative in this case is $\frac{-2n}{\theta}<0$, then you need to take the smallest value value allowed by the domain, which is $\hat \theta = \max_{i}(y_i)$

Comment: Good work @P.Quinton even my revision was wrong, my $y_n$ isn't necessarily $max(y_i)$. Thankyou.

Comment: Any pointers to some literature that talks about this @P.Quinton ? what terms would I search for. I have never seen that kind of notation before. In fact, please explain more the first line: $\ln\big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i \mathbb 1(y_i\leq \theta)\big)$

Comment: Observe that the likelihood of $y_i$ is given by $2 \frac{y_i}{\theta} \mathbb 1(y_i\leq \theta)$ for $y_i\geq 0$, this is because I included in the distribution the fact that $y_i\leq \theta$. Now the thing is that $\prod_{i=1}^n y_i \mathbb{1}(y_i\leq \theta) = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n y_i  \right) \cdot\left( \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(y_i\leq \theta)  \right)$ and the second term means that we need to have $y_i\leq \theta$ for all $i\in[1:n]$ that is, the max of all $y_i$ needs to be less then $\theta$. In the end you can write that $\mathbb{1}(\max_i y_i\leq \theta)$

Comment: This first part is the part that is puzzling me: $2 \frac{y_i}{\theta} \mathbb 1(y_i\leq \theta$. That notation. I'm not familiar with it. Is that part in the brackets a condition on $y_i$? is that an operation? I have never seen such a term.

Comment: the $\mathbb 1$ is the indicator function which is one if the given condition is satisfied, and zero otherwise. Also it is $2\frac{y_i}{\theta^2}\mathbb 1(y_i\leq \theta)$, I made a typo.

Comment: ok, so I will google "indicator function" thankyou very much.